# Winsock 2 Reading text from a URL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winsock, winsock2

For example, this is what I'm wanting to do:

```
    if (http->Connect("http://pastebin.com/raw/9uL16CyN"))
    {
        YString data = "";
        if (http->ReceiveData(data))
        {
            std::cout << "Networked data: " << std::endl;
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Failed to connect to internet.\n";
    }
```

The page I'm trying to read from is a raw ASCII text (http://pastebin.com/raw/9uL16CyN)

I was hoping this would work easily, but apparently not, I keep getting the WSA error: **WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND (11001)**

My Connect function:

```
bool Http::Connect(YString addr)
{
    _socket = Network::CreateConnectSocket(addr, 53); // 53 is the port
    return _socket != INVALID_SOCKET;
}
```

CreateConnectSocket function:

```
int iResult;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

// holds address info for socket to connect to
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
    *ptr = NULL,
    hints;

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;  //TCP connection!!!

                                  //resolve server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(addr.c_str(), std::to_string(port).c_str(), &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0)
{
    printf("Network::CreateSocket failed with %s as addr, and %i as port.\nError code: %i.\n", (char*)addr.c_str(), port, iResult);
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Network::CreateSocket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        printf("Network::CreateSocket failed the server is down... did not connect.\n");
    }
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Network::CreateSocket failed.\n");
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

u_long iMode = 1;
iResult = ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Network::CreateSocket ioctlsocket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}
char value = 1;
setsockopt(ConnectSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &value, sizeof(value));
return ConnectSocket;
```

Most of its taken from existing sources.

Comment: Why was my answer removed?
NVM wrong post lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `Connect()` is wrong.  You cannot pass the full URL to `getaddrinfo()`.  You need to pass only the domain name and port number by themselves.  BTW, the HTTP port is 80, not 53.

Also, you are not sending an HTTP `GET` request to the server asking it to send you the text document.  An HTTP server will not send a response until you send a request first.

You need something more like this instead:

```
bool Http::Connect(YString addr, int port)
{
    _socket = Network::CreateConnectSocket(addr, port);
    return _socket != INVALID_SOCKET;
}
```

```
if (http->Connect("pastebin.com", 80))
{
    YString data = "GET /raw/9uL16CyN HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                   "Host: pastebin.com\r\n"
                   "Connection: close\r\n"
                   "\r\n";

    if (http->SendData(data))
    {
        YString data = "";
        if (http->ReceiveData(data))
        {
            std::cout << "Networked data: " << std::endl;
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Failed to receive data from internet.\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Failed to send request to Pastebin.\n";
}
else
    std::cout << "Failed to connect to Pastebin.\n";
```

That being said, you need to take into account that the server is going to frame the response data with headers, eg:

```
GET /raw/9uL16CyN HTTP/1.1
Host: pastebin.com
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 00:00:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db6ba4b037d673b67757500aca4e2227b1450828801; expires=Thu, 22-Dec-16 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.pastebin.com; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.5
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1801
Vary: Accept-Encoding
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Expires: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 00:30:02 GMT
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 258fc8a8168a2276-LAX

2a
Text, text, text, text! Some more text! :D
0
```

So, assuming `ReceiveData()` is just returning whatever it receives, you will have to strip those headers off, and undo the `chunked` encoding, before you can use the content of the text file by itself.  Please read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (or its successors RFCs 7230-7235), which outline the HTTP protocol in detail.

That being said, you should stop trying to implement HTTP manually (it is more complex then you realize) and use a pre-existing library instead, just as [`libcurl`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), or even Microsoft's own [`WinInet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385331.aspx) or [`WinHTTP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384273.aspx) APIs.  Let them do the heavy work for you.